# How to tell when a swf has finished loading from javascript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I need to know when my swf is ready to start playing (e.g. the initial loader has finished downloading). I know I can use `ExternalInterface.call('someJSFunc')` in a `[loader][1]` handler within the swf, but if possible, I'd rather not have that dependency.

Is there better a way just within JS? The only thing I've come up with so far is something like:

```
// continually check if the flash is ready
var int = setInterval(function(){
    var fl = $('#flashMovie').get(0);
    if (fl) {
        doThings();
        clearInterval(int);
    }
}, 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

`swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrl, id, width, height, version, expressInstallSwfurl, flashvars, params, attributes, callbackFn)`

Not sure if this will help you but the last parameter to swfobject is a callback function that gets called when the swf  tag is created.

`callbackFn (JavaScript function, optional) can be used to define a callback function that is called on both success or failure of creating a Flash plug-in <object> on the page (see API documentation)`

More info [here](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) :

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I saw that in another question. Unfortunately, that tells me that the tag was created, but doesn't tell me anything about whether or not it was downloaded.